# How to get aarch64 version of musl on Debian for qemu user mode

Tags: qemu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, arm64

I'm running Kali Linux on a Windows Subsystem for Linux v1 (WSL). This failed on WSL v2 as well if that means anything. I have an ARM aarch64 binary I want to run. I have qemu user mode and I try running it with `qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/ binary_name` but I get the error

```
/lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1: No such file or directory
```

I've installed the packages

```
sudo apt-get install install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf libc6-dev-armhf-cross qemu-user-static libc6-dev-arm64-cross gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

what else do I need to get the ARM64 `musl` library on my Debian system?

Sorry if I'm asking the wrong question, I'm really new to qemu user mode.

EDIT:

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
arm64
$ sudo apt update
Hit:2 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Get:3 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Packages [16.7 MB]
Ign:3 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Packages
Get:4 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/non-free arm64 Packages [143 kB]
Get:4 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/non-free arm64 Packages [143 kB]
Ign:4 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/non-free arm64 Packages
Ign:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Packages
Ign:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free arm64 Packages
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (16750562 != 16747652). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: <IP>]
18% [Working]E: Transaction http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease was already aborted and is aborted again
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free arm64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (143487 != 143485). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: <IP>]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Transaction http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease was already aborted and is aborted again
$ sudo apt install musl_arm64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package musl_arm64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the `arm64` architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
```

Then update the package indexes:

```
sudo apt update
```

Once the update completes *successfully* (which isn’t the case in your edit), you’ll be able to install `musl` for `arm64`:

```
sudo apt install musl:arm64
```

Comment: I tried to do this but it says `Unable to locate package musl:arm64`

Comment: Even after `dpkg --add-architecture arm64` and `apt update`?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if `musl` is the exact name of the package on ARM64. I know the missing link object in the error message appears to be from musl but I'm not sure where to get the ARM64 version.

Comment: The package is `musl`, and has been since [Debian 8](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/musl). I’m using this solution on my own system to run MUSL Aarch64 binaries using QEMU. I’m not sure why `apt` can’t find `musl:arm64` on your system...

Comment: What does `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` say?

Comment: Exactly what I was going to comment with `# dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
arm64
$ sudo apt update
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main arm64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (16750562 != 16747652). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: <IP>]
18% [Working]E: Transaction http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease was already aborted and is aborted again
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free arm64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (143487 != 143485). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: <IP>]
Reading package lists... Done`

Comment: Ah, so `apt update` failed, you need a successful `apt update`; without that, `apt install musl:arm64` won’t work.

Comment: Do you know what the issue might be? (just added error messages to main post)

Comment: The error message gives a hint: “Mirror sync in progress?” You’ll need to wait and try again later.

Comment: When I remove `arm64` from the `dpkg` architecures, my `apt update` works fine, but the moment I add it back, it seems `apt update` fails.

Comment: Yes, the `arm64` repo on the mirror is messed up. You need to wait and try again later.

Comment: Understood, thank you.